# Purpose of comma in r.mapcalc in GRASS GIS 7.4

Tags: grass-gis, r.mapcalc

I would like to know the purpose of a comma in [r.mapcalc](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass74/manuals/r.mapcalc.html) of GRASS GIS. Consider this example -

```
r.mapcalc "noise = if(landuse96_28m==1 || landuse96_28m==2, roads_buffers, null())"
```

---

In the above example I know the statement means if landuse96_28m is equal to 1 OR landuse96_28m is equal to 2 but after this last digit I get confused as to what the  comma(,) stands for as well as the one after the roads_buffers.

If someone would explain to me in a straightforward manner what the comma(,) means I will receive a breakthrough in using r.mapcalc.

Answer (score 2):

There are three components to that `if()` statement, separated by the two commas. Component 1 is a logical condition that returns True or False. Component 2 is what happens if the condition is True. Component three is what happens if the condition is False. Presumably, if the condition is True, the output pixel in 'noise' is assigned a value from the overlying pixel in 'roads_buffers'. If not, it is assigned the value `null`.

Answer (score 0):

To add to obri_soil's answer, your statement more generally can be explained as:

"The layer 'noise' will be returned as 'road_buffers' if the 'landuse' layer has either of value 1 or 2. If landuse has any other values other than 1 or 2, you will get null/ no data"